# Java: Getting photo click effect after screenshot

Tags: java, swing, screenshot

I have written two classes, `FullScreen`, which contains the logic for the screenshot, and `FullScreenGUI`, which contains the logic for simulating the *photo click* effect.

The *photo click* effect is basically flashing the screen with white color for a short period of time, say 50ms after the screenshot is taken. It is produced by covering the whole screen by a `JFrame` with an opacity of 1%. The background is made white and then the opacity is changed from 1% to 100%, kept like that for 50ms, then back to 1%.

The `FullScreen` constructor takes two parameters, one for number of times to take screenshot, and the other for the duration in between.

The `FullScreenGUI` constructs a `JFrame`, maximises it, sets the background to white. When the `fire()` method is called, it changes the opacity as required to produce the effect.

**The Question:**

Using the code below I am able to produce the effect for the first time the screenshot is taken, but not for the subsequent clicks. Suppose, `FullScreen` constructor is called with the parameters `(4,2)` (i.e. to take 4 clicks each at 2 seconds duration), then the effect is produced nicely for the first click but not for the remaining 3 clicks. `JFrame` of the `FullScreenGUI` does not seem to come to front, so the effect is not visible. I have tried `JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`, `JFrame.toFront()` but they don't seem to bring the `JFrame` to the top.

There is no problem in taking the screenshot, but instead with the effect. Do you have any other ideas to produce it ?

Here is the **code**:

`FullScreen.java`

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

class FullScreen
{   
    int times, duration;
    Timer t;
    Robot r;
    BufferedImage bi;
    FullScreenGUI fg;

FullScreen(int tim, int duration) 
{
    fg = new FullScreenGUI();
    fg.setVisible(true);
    this.times = tim;
    this.duration = duration;
    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Inside constructor");
    t = new Timer(duration*1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            System.out.println("Inside action");
            if(times>0)
            {
                System.out.println("times: "+times);

                //Get the screenshot
                bi = capture();

                //Gives the path of the home directory. For windows, it'll go to your desktop
                FileSystemView filesys = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
                File fl = filesys.getHomeDirectory();
                saveImage(bi, fl);

                //Produces the "clicking" effect
                fg.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                fg.toFront();
                fg.fire();

                times--;
            }
            else
                t.stop();
        }
    });
}

public void fire()
{
    t.start();
}

public void saveImage(BufferedImage source, File destination)
{
    System.out.println("Inside saveimage");
    if(destination.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println("destination: "+destination.getAbsolutePath());
        String tmp = destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Screenshot";
        String str;
        int i=1;
        for(str=tmp; (new File(str+".png").exists()); i++)
        {
            str = tmp + "_" + String.valueOf(i);
            System.out.println("trying: "+str);
        }

        try {
            ImageIO.write(source, "png", new File(str+".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public BufferedImage capture()
{
    System.out.println("Captured");
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    return r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(d));
}

public static void main(String arg[])
{
    //click 4 times each at an interval of 2 seconds
    FullScreen f = new FullScreen(4,2);

    f.fire();
    while(f.t.isRunning());
}
}
```

`FullScreenGUI.java`

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class FullScreenGUI extends JFrame {

FullScreenGUI()
{
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setOpacity(0.01f);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    jl.setBackground(Color.white);
    add(jl);        

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void fire()
{
    System.out.println("click");
    setVisible(true);

    try{

    setOpacity(1f);
    Thread.sleep(50);
    setOpacity(0.1f);

    }catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    setVisible(false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is `Thread.sleep(50);`.

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for this task. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: .-), I sure that EDT must be freezed, please see linked post in my deleted post, Swing Timer is contraproductive, Merry Christmast to your easiest corner of the world

Comment: Isn't Christmas tomorrow guys? :P right now its 24/12/2012 04:44PM CAT.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp It's been Christmas for the last 1h45m here (Sydney).  The rest of the world should catch up!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Haha I though timezones would clash :) merry Christmas (and previously +1 for great answer) wish I could do it again for answering on christmas :P